# Is there any law limiting the extent to which one can grow brains in a lab in the United States? (e.g., max number of neurons, synapses, etc.)

Tags: united-states, medical, research

Is there any law limiting the extent to which one can grow brains / brain organoids in a lab in the United States (e.g., max number of neurons, synapses, etc.)? E.g. to study brain diseases {1} or add biological neurons into traditional silicon computing device {2}.

---

References:

- {1}  Benam, Kambez H., Stephanie Dauth, Bryan Hassell, Anna Herland, Abhishek Jain, Kyung-Jin Jang, Katia Karalis et al. "Engineered in vitro disease models." Annual Review of Pathology: Mechanisms of Disease 10 (2015): 195-262. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-pathol-012414-040418
- {2} https://www.cclabs.ai/

Comment: I'm not sure why there would be.  Do you mean human brain cells?

Comment: @RossRidge human or another animal. Motivation to legislate: might be able to grow functioning human-size brain at some point, hopefully in a near future.

Comment: Just a comment on the science, not the law. While you can certainly grow neurons in a lab, the only place you can grow a brain is in an embryo - a brain is integrally linked to the body.

Comment: @DaleM https://www.theguardian.com/science/2019/mar/18/scientists-grow-mini-brain-on-the-move-that-can-contract-muscle  "Scientists have grown a miniature brain in a dish with a spinal cord and muscles attached, an advance that promises to accelerate the study of conditions such as motor neurone disease."